# SDK Build Tools revision too low

Tags: android, cordova

I'm getting this error when I build the android app:

Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.0.0) is too low for project ':CordovaLib'. Minimum required is 19.1.0

I've looked at other posts, and their solutions didn't work for me. I tried editing build.gradle and changed buildToolsVersion.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'android'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.+'
    }
}

ext.multiarch=false

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    for (subproject in getProjectList()) {
        compile project(subproject)
    }
}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode Integer.parseInt("" + getVersionCodeFromManifest() + "0")
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
```

Also, in my SDK manager, I have everything installed.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but this is my manifest file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="com.phonegap.helloworld" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
</manifest>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is complaining about the `:CordovaLib` module, not your main module - make sure the `build.gradle` file for that module is using at least build tools 19.1.0 (or try updating Cordova).